# EmojiconEditText is adding the emojis from the beginning

Tags: android, emoji

I am creating a Instant chat application .I am using library  compile `com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3` to add emoticons in my application.

[image: Screenshot]

In the screenshot we have an `EmojiEditText` whose left drawable is emoji icon and right drawable is Send icon.ON clicking emoji icon a panel of emoticons is displayed as we can see in the screenshot.The emoji selected through emoji panel is displayed in the edittext .On cliking emojiedittext soft keyboard is displayed .My problem is when i am clicking on emoji icon new emoji is always entered from the beginning .It is not inserted in its actual location.It means suppose i am selecting some emoji ,then writing some text using `softkeyboard` .After that if i select emoji ,it is added to the leftmost side of editext .Please help me to fix the issue.

**activity_single_chat.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_single_chat"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarSingleChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#09436B"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".90"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
                android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight=".10"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/emoticons"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding10"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/send"
                android:hint="Type your message ..."
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding10"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding10" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/emojicons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".00"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Initializing EmojiconEditText**

```
 EmojiconEditText edMessage = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
```

**On clicking the EmojiconEditText**

```
// On clicking the edit text Emoji panel will be hidden
    edMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hideEmoji = true;
            hideEmojiPopUp(hideEmoji);
            showKeyboard(edMessage);
        }
    });
```

**hideEmojiPopup**

```
// Hiding the FrameLayout containing the list of Emoticons
public void hideEmojiPopUp(boolean hideEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**showKeyboard**

```
 //Show the soft keyboard
public void showKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    hideEmojiPopUp(true);
    //setHeightOfEmojiEditText();
}
```

**On touching EmojiconEditText**

```
//Handling click event on drawableLeft and drawableRight inside  EmojiconEditText
edMessage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                                     final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                                     final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                                     final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                                     final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
                                     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                         //Handling drawableRight
                                         int leftEdgeOfRightDrawable = edMessage.getRight() - edMessage.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width();
                                         //EditText has padding here.So adjust left edge
                                         leftEdgeOfRightDrawable -= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding10); //Here we have set the padding of 10 from left and right in edittext
                                         if (event.getRawX() >= leftEdgeOfRightDrawable) {
                                             // your action here
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             message = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();

                                             // Spannable s = getSmiledText(getApplicationContext(),message);
                                             //  Log.e("Spannable", String.valueOf(s));
                                             // Encoding emoji into unicode characters
                                             String toServer = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);
                                             //To find the current time in timestamp format
                                             Date d = new Date();
                                             final long time = d.getTime();
                                             Log.e("Time", String.valueOf(time));
                                             Log.e("To Server", toServer);
                                             Log.e("Sending", "Sending data-----" + toServer);
                                             if (!message.equals("")) {
                                                 edMessage.setText(" ");
                                                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                                                 try {
                                                     jsonObject.put("room_id", md5StringRoomID);
                                                     jsonObject.put("user", loggedInUpper);
                                                     jsonObject.put("id", friendID);
                                                     jsonObject.put("message", toServer);
                                                     jsonObject.put("date", time);
                                                     jsonObject.put("status", "sent");

                                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                                 }
                                                 // isSelf = true; // Boolean isSelf is set to be true as sender of the message is logged in user i.e. you
                                                 //attemptToSend(loggedInUpper, message, isSelf);
                                                 mSocket.emit("send", jsonObject); // owner i.e LoggedIn user is sending the message
           /* msg = new Bean_Message();
            msg.setMessageStatus(Status.SENT);
            listBeanMessages.add(msg);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                                             } else {
                                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void run() {
                                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                     }
                                                 });
                                             }
                                             return true;
                                         }

                                         //Handling drawable Left
                                         if (event.getRawX() <= (edMessage.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width())) {
                                             // your action here
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             hideKeyboard();  // hiding the keyboard
                                             showEmojiPopUp(!showEmoji);
                                             return true;

                                         }
                                     }
                                     return false;
                                 }
                             }
```

**Hiding the keyboard:**

```
 // Hiding the keyboard
    public void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

**Showing the emoji popup**

```
 public void showEmojiPopUp(boolean showEmoji) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    deviceHeight = size.y;
    Log.e("Device Height", String.valueOf(deviceHeight));
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (deviceHeight / 2.5); // Setting the height of FrameLayout
    frameLayout.requestLayout();
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    hideKeyboard();
}
```

**Replacing frame with a fragment of Emoticons**

```
 // This method will set a panel of emoticons in the fragment
private void setEmojiconFragment(boolean useSystemDefault) {
    // Replacing the existing frame having id emojicons with the fragment of emoticons library containing emoticons
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.emojicons, EmojiconsFragment.newInstance(useSystemDefault)).commit();
}
```

**On clicking Backspace**

```
@Override
public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View view) {
    EmojiconsFragment.backspace(edMessage);
}
```

**On clicking Emoji**

```
@Override
public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
    EmojiconsFragment.input(edMessage, emojicon);
}
```

Comment: I believe its something in encoding , provide a piece of your code

Comment: @MinaFawzy :Please check my edited code.

Comment: @MinaFawzy you checked my code?Please help me as i am unable to find the solution .

Answer (score 0):

you could try overide this methods `OnEmojiconClickedListener`, `OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener` and edittext should be type of `EmojiconEditText` not normal EditText

code snapshot

```
public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        EmojiconGridFragment.OnEmojiconClickedListener, EmojiconsFragment.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener { 

    EmojiconEditText edMessage = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage); // emoji edittext
 @Override 
    public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View view) {
        EmojiconsFragment.backspace(edMessage);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        EmojiconsFragment.input(edMessage, emojicon);
    } 

}
```

Comment: I have already used the code mentioned by you.Still it is not working.

Comment: It is working fine when i am only adding emoji one after another.After adding a few emoji if i enter some text and then click on emoji icon and try to add emoticons it is added in the beginning.This is my problem .

Comment: but sir as I see in input(EditText editText, Emojicon emojicon) you are using EditText ? not  EmojiconEditText

Comment: Oh that is the method inside EmojiFragment.class specified by library.I am sure i am using the same code as is mentioned by you.